# How do I disable the reordering of an element in react-sortable-hoc. Passing disabled prop to SortableListItem doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript, react-dnd, react-sortable-hoc

I have my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-rhodes-q9gk4o?file=/src/index.js) and I am trying to restrict the change of order of Item 2. Passing disabled prop doesn't allow me to drag the Item2, but if I drag/drop elements above/below Item2, then the order of Item2 also gets changed. How can I restrict that from happening?

Comment: Seems this is currently not supported It can only be possible one the first index https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/648